# Calculating number of values less than x by row of data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, dataframe

I have searched the forums and the web high and low for the last two days, and broken down my script to try and find the issue, but for some reason, I can't get this to work properly beyond the first row:

```
numbers <- mtcars[1:6,]

nnn <- c(1:(nrow(numbers)))

for (i in nnn){
  ly <- numbers[i,]
  numbers[i,12]<- sum(abs(ly) < 5e0)
}
```

This returns:

```
> numbers
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb V12
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  NA
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  NA
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  NA
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  NA
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  NA
```

As you can see, when i is 1, ly is the mazda rx4 row, and it performs

```
sum(abs(ly) < 5e0)
```

correctly, placing the value 6 in a new 12th column. However, beyond that, even though I've determined that it is looping through i correctly, and returning ly correctly for each iteration of i, its not calculating the sum part for rows 2:5

Its probably really obvious to most what I am doing wrong here, but for the life of me I can't pick it. I'm new to R and programming, self taught pretty much, and I've written quite a few successul for loops and scripts so far in the last few weeks, but this has me dumfounded. Someone else in our research group who uses Matlab went through it with me, the problem down the same as I did, and she couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work either.

I've used mtcars so far just to test the loop and so that its easily accessible to those on the forum. Once I know it works, I'll translate it for my dataset (which is quite large).

Comment: +1 for a specific question, including a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using for loops is generally not necessary in R. A more R-like solution is to use `apply`:

```
apply(numbers, 1, function(x) sum(abs(x) < 5e0))
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive
                6                 6                 7                 6
Hornet Sportabout           Valiant
                6                 6
```

Adding it as a column simply involves:

```
numbers$V12 = apply(numbers, 1, function(x) sum(abs(x) < 5e0))
```

Some remarks on your code:

- There is no need to wrap `1:(nrow(numbers))` with `c`.
- Generating the index vector can more easily be done using `seq_len`, i.e. `seq_len(nrow(numbers))`.

Comment: I've people reply to forum questions that they should use the apply et all tools...they generally dumfound me at the moment, which is why I went with a for loop :-|

Comment: However, your example using my situation makes much more sense. Thanks! I'll give all these solutions on here a go, to learn from them. Will be interesting to see which is faster in my case (I'll add timers).

Comment: @AdamKilpatrick `apply` style looping is something you need to get used to. Once you are, generally it leads to more compact code, and sometimes to speed increases. Although a `for` is perfectly valid in R, the compactness for me is what sells it.

Answer (score 2):

After your first iteration, the `V12` column is added to your `numbers` data.frame. Because that column contains `NA` from the second row, all subsequent iterations will include a `NA` in the `sum(abs(ly) < 5e0)` operation, hence returning `NA`. A quick fix is to add `na.rm = TRUE` to that `sum` call. But as @Paul points out, there are much better ways of doing what you are trying to achieve. One of them:

```
numbers$extra.col <- rowSums(abs(numbers) < 5)
```

Comment: Dang, I just spotted it like you did +1!

Comment: Another good option would be to first build a vector inside the loop, and then assign it to `mtcars` afterwards.

Comment: Ahh I see. This makes a lot of sense as to why the NA's are there.

Comment: building a vector in the loop first sounds good...I guess after the loop I assing it to mtcars with cbind...?

Comment: Or simply use `number$extra.col = vector_built_in_loop`, like @flodel uses in his answer.